# How to get Incremental Data in MySql

Tags: mysql, database

I need to get the data that has been changed(only the delta) in a MySql database since the past x hours..
To be a bit more precise, i need the rows of data that were updated/deleted/created in the past x hours
Is there a way to get that data in a generic way in MySql regardless of the storage engine used (InnoDB/MyISAM)??

Comment: Just add a `lastModified` column and use that to filter in your queries.

Comment: Yes just like @RobbyCornelissen said. Add a column named `lastModified` or `row_update_time` of `timestamp` data type and set it `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Any way it could be achieved without an extra column being added? ..Does MySql keep track of the changed data?

Comment: Run this query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'log_bin';` and what's the result?

Comment: @Subrata Dey Pappu : it gives out OFF...  Also i just have read acces to the database...so i wont be able to create triggers,add new columns etc...

Comment: Then I am afraid there's an way to retrieve information like that.